# How do I upscale a 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3] video to crop out black bars?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, vlc-media-player, video-encoding

I have a movie from one of my DVDs looking like the following after having imported it and muxed it to a `.mkv` container:
[image]

`ffprobe`` provides me with the following information:
[image]

I recently imported another one of my DVDs, which completely fills out the picture at `720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9]`. What specifically causes the black bars to appear and at what ratio would I need to upscale the movie without cropping out parts of the frames and is it possible at all? I read somewhere I should upscale based on multiples of the source file pixels.

Comment: Your DAR (display aspect ratio) for the first move was 16:9, which fills up the typical widescreen display (1920x1080, which if you divide both terms with 120 is 16/9). Your second movie has a DAR if 4:3, which corresponds with the old type of almost square displays. Playing back 4:3 material on a 16:9 display and filling the screen would result in the picture being stretched 4 times horizontally (4->16) but only 3 times vertically (3->9), resulting in a stretched and skewed image. To prevent this, you only scale 3 times (4:3 -> 12:9) and add black bars on the left and right.

Comment: Because of this, you cant simply upscale to fix the problem. The fix for your problem is simply dropping some of the original image (horizontal lines). However, this is almost never something you want to do, and i would suggest living with the black bars and enjoying the movie as it was supposed to.

Comment: @Silbee But playing the content doesn't look like a 4:3 aspect ratio - the visible picture is marginally longer horizontally than it is vertically. This is also what confuses me because 4:3 should be completely squared - does the SAR play any role in this?

Comment: SAR shouldnt play a roll. Mind you that often times (especially on TV's) old 4:3 content already gets a bit stretched and zoomed on widescreen displays to have as much picture and as little black bars on the side as possible. Its a built in 'convenience' that is almost always enabled by default. And 4:3 isnt squared, it becomes 12:9, add in some magic zoomies and stretching by the TV and you're quickly at 14:9 almost covering your 16:9 screen. Just look at it by the maths, you cant fit 4:3 onto 16:9 without either black bars or missing picture.